# How do i check whether a collection has been eager loaded with Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I recently used the following code

```
     var errorCount =
                split.Profiles.SelectMany(p => p.Logs)
                    .Count(l => l.LogTypeId == (int)LogType.Error);
```

errorCount returned zero because I forgot to include my logs table when I built the split entity.

How can I detect whether the split.Profiles.Logs collection has been eager loaded?

I am using Model First.

the class for Profile is

```
   public partial class Profile
{
    public Profile()
    {
        this.Log = new HashSet<Log>();
    }

    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    public int SplitId { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime EndTime { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Log> Log { get; set; }
    public virtual SplitUpload SplitUpload { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show me your `Profile` model?

Comment: I think you can check if it's loaded fully or partially but you cannot check if it's loaded by eager-loading or lazying-loading or explicit-loading. Why do you need to know about that?

Comment: because the errorcount returns zero if it not loaded, and the correct count of errors if it is loaded.  Which leads to bad bugs.

Comment: @kirsteng Try see your condition `l.LogTypeId == (int)LogType.Error` remove that and try count to see have data in your `Log` property.

Comment: @Hopeless  I just need to check if it is loaded. How do I do that?

Comment: @Jones, count will return a value.  but that wont tell me if the zero is because there are no entries or the zero is because the collection is not loaded.

Comment: I understand that `split.Profiles` is `IEnumerable<...>`, otherwise if it's `IQueryable<...>` the `p.Logs` will be translated to query against Log table and does not require the `p.Logs`to be loaded. So in the `SelectMany` you can use the `dbContext.Entry(p).Collection("Logs").IsLoaded` to check if the nav collection has been loaded. I think you should use the `Load()` (instead of `IsLoaded`) to load the collection, existing entities won't be overwritten. I believe `Load()` will just load non-loaded entities.

Comment: thankyou @Hopeless  I tried dbContext.Entry(p).Collection("Logs").IsLoaded but I get an error
 The entity type HashSet'1 is not part of the model for the current context.

Comment: @Hopeless you pointed me in the right direct.  First I had to check the first collection was loaded. Then I needed to check that if it had any members then their child collection was also loaded.  Would you like to write up the answer?

Comment: no thanks, I'm glad you got your own solution from what I suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hopeless you pointed me in the right direct. First I had to check the first collection was loaded. Then I needed to check that if it had any members then their child collection was also loaded